# Blending for CSS gradients behaves unexpectedly

Tags: css, linear-gradients, css-gradients

I'm creating a CSS linear gradient with [`color-hint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient#syntax)s and I want to create an effect to blend from one color to the background color on one side, and then do the opposite to blend back on the other side.

Unfortunately, the blending for the colors is not consistent so one side looks different than the other (on Edge Chromium).

You can see the effect with the below snippet:

For the first div, blend from left to right starting from blue and ending in orange.  The midpoint for the blend should be 75% of the way across.

```css
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, 75%, orange);
```

For the second div, blend from left to right starting from orange, and ending in blue.  The midpoint for the blend should be 25% of the way across (from the right).

```css
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, orange, 25%, blue);
```

I would expect these gradients to be identical since the midpoint is at the exact same point, but you can see that it's different.  The midpoint is in the correct location and the color seems to match, but the blending between the midpoint and the blue side seems off.  If orange is the "starting" color (the second gradient going from the right) then it seems to have more influence on the final color.

The last two divs show that if the mid-point is at 50% then the blending is the same.

Is there a way to fix this or do I just need to manually add my own stop using the midpoint color and avoid using `color-hint`s?

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, 75%, orange);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, orange, 25%, blue);
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, 50%, orange);
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, orange, 50%, blue);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
<main>
```

*Edit:*
Here's another image that makes it even more clear

[image: obvious gradient issues]

The first portion of the gradient (e.g. 0% up to X%) should smoothly change from the first color to the midpoint, but you can see that it's mostly the first color, and only starts to transition close to the `color-hint` point.

But the second portion (X% to 100%) properly uses the entire length to transition so it's a smooth gradient from the first color to the midpoint color.

Comment: Could the implementation for color stops provide a hint to why this happens? I have yet to figure it out, https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/core/css/CSSGradientValue.cpp

Comment: I don't know *why* this is happening, but I may have a workaround if you want something that looks the same on the left and the right: You can mirror the effect using `transform: scale(-1, 1);` and with low effort you'll have something identical on both sides (well, symmetrically identical, I mean).

Comment: it has to do with defining the midpoint like ```(black, 25%, white)```. 
what works is ```(to right, black 25%, white 100%)``` and ```(to left, white 0%, black 75%)``` do look identical. why this happens, no idea.

Comment: @niorad - Yeah, if I manually figure out the midpoint color myself, then I can construct the gradient I want without using the `color-hint` but the color's are dynamic so it's annoying to do in CSS.

Comment: Yes but with the other syntax I mentioned it works and you don't need to know the midpoint-color

Comment: The gradient produced by `(black, 25%, white)` is not the same as `(to right, black 25%, white 100%)`.  

The first produces a gradient that starts at black, fades to gray (25% of the way across) and then fades from that gray to white for the remaining 75%.  

The second produces a gradient that starts at black and continues as black up till 25% of the way across, and then fades from black to white.